# Put an X button to an iAd banner

Tags: xcode

how can you out an x button on a iAd banner OR how do you set a timed duration to it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `IBOutlet` and an `NSTimer` to do so. Link up the `IBOutlet` to your iAd object, then use the `NSTimer` to make it fade out with `UIView`'s animation methods.